# I changed my base URL from http to https and now my site is inaccessible

Tags: magento-1.9, 404-page, base-url

I was trying to set up my magento store to use the ssl certificate I just bought and was told to change the base url to https instead of http.

Now the site and magento admin is inaccessible and I get the following 404 page:

[image]

Was it a bad idea to change the base url to https and is there any way I can fix this? Thank you

Comment: tell me your change you have done for change base url ?

Comment: I ask to check it, please provide me  your email address.

Answer (score 1):

Find table (core_config_data) from database.

### Search below paths under path column:

(web/unsecure/base_url)  & set Url without https.

(web/secure/base_url) & set Url with https.

After that your website will work.

Answer (score 0):

Set Secure base url like : https://www.youdomainurl.com/

Do not change unsecure url it must be : http://www.youdomainurl.com/

Use Secure URLs in Frotnend set to "**Yes**"

Bellow screen shot example for it.

[image]

if you can not access admin then you have to change base url directly from database.

Table : **core_config_data**, change values of

> web/secure/base_url

in path column **https://** to **http://**